# Solve Domino chain using recursive backtracking

Tags: c++, recursion

given a vector of dominos my program should be able to match them and put them in order if not solvable it returns false. Here's what i have, it works when it is solvable for any order of dominoes but it doesn't return false if it's not solvable:

```
bool SolveDominoChain(Vector<Domino> & chain, Vector<Domino> & remaining)
{
    int remainingSize = remaining.size();

    Vector<Domino>tempRemaining = remaining;
    Vector<Domino>tempChain = chain;

    if(remaining.isEmpty())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if(chain.isEmpty())
        {
            chain.add(remaining[0]);
            remaining.removeAt(0);
            chain[0].flip();        
            return SolveDominoChain(chain, 
        }
        for(int d = 0; d< remainingSize; d++)
        {
            if(chain[chain.size()-1].getBottom() == remaining[d].getTop())
            {
                chain.add(remaining[d]);
                remaining.removeAt(d);
                return SolveDominoChain(chain, remaining);
            }
            if(chain[chain.size()-1].getBottom() == remaining[d].getBottom())
            {
                remaining[d].flip();
                chain.add(remaining[d]);
                remaining.removeAt(d);
                return SolveDominoChain(chain, remaining);
            }

            remaining.add(chain[chain.size()-1]);
            chain.removeAt(chain.size()-1);

            return SolveDominoChain(chain, remaining);
        }           
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I can't see any way for the `return false` statements to be reached. If `remaining` is empty it will return true, otherwise it is guaranteed to recurse into `SolveDominoChain` again. Was there supposed to be an if test around that last oddly indented block?

Comment: Ya im not sure how to stop if from recursing once it's tested all available options. Any ideas?

Comment: At the moment it will never go around the `for(int d` loop more than once. I think you need to take a step back and work out what you want your algorithm to do, maybe even try it with actual dominoes by hand. Then try to code it.